# Angular variables with Blockly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blockly

I have Blockly blocks with text input

In my starter block, I want to set the text input to an angular variable. 
But right now, it says my variable is `{{var}}` and it evaluates to `output`.

What currently happens is, the block initially shows `output` but if I evaluate it to code or click on the text input, it reverts to show `{{var}}` in the text input.

Could someone explain why that happens? Here is the relevant code; the starter blocks:

```
<xml id="startBlocks" style="display: none" >
    <block type="given" inline="false" x="20" y="20"><field name="LINE"> {{pageInfo.exercise.title}}</field></block>
</xml>
```

I receive pageInfo from a GET:

```
$http.get('/api/exercise')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.pageInfo = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

Comment: did you try without the expression like "var"?

Comment: Can you show relevant code block.

Comment: Editted to show relevant code, and yes, I did try without an expression.